# Word for person who takes care of something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm making a software form in which the user needs to specify the person from within the organization who needs to address a certain repair or other technical issue (e.g., custodian) as well as the person from an external organization who is responsible.

What is a good title for "person taking care of problem"?

I contemplated assignee, but felt that it can only refer to someone within the organization, because I can't assign someone external to a task. So perhaps that is a good title for one field, but the other (external) is still needed.

Comment: Google `caretaker synonym`

Answer (score 2):

Words specific to the context of organizations:

1. Supervisor
2. Manager
3. Handler
4. Attender
5. Undertaker

Words having a generic context:

1. Caretaker
2. Caregiver
3. Dealer
4. Nurse